# Python wrapper to run a scala class

Tags: python, scala, maven

I have a maven scala project with a scala object (myObject) like this

projectname

- src

  - main

    - scala

      - utils

        - myObject

myObject has a main function defined as

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 --stuff
}
```

I need to create a python wrapper script that will essentially get some arguments from the user, and pass those arguments to that myObject. How would I go about doing this? So far I have a python script with a main that uses argparse to take in some arguements, but unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: You probably want to produce an uber jar with your code and let your **Python** script to invoke `java - jar foo.jar arg1 arg2` In any case, why not read the arguments in the **Scala** code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand precisely, Py4j is the library you are looking to run as essentially scala compiles to JVM bytecode, you can run either scala or java methods using py4j.

here is the abstract from py4j website home page:

Py4J enables Python programs running in a Python interpreter to dynamically access Java objects in a Java Virtual Machine. Methods are called as if the Java objects resided in the Python interpreter and Java collections can be accessed through standard Python collection methods. Py4J also enables Java programs to call back Python objects. Py4J is distributed under the BSD license.

Here is a brief example of what you can do with Py4J. The following Python program creates a java.util.Random instance from a JVM and calls some of its methods. It also accesses a custom Java class, AdditionApplication to add the generated numbers.

```
>>> from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
>>> gateway = JavaGateway()                   # connect to the JVM
>>> random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()   # create a java.util.Random instance
>>> number1 = random.nextInt(10)              # call the Random.nextInt method
>>> number2 = random.nextInt(10)
>>> print(number1, number2)
(2, 7)
>>> addition_app = gateway.entry_point               # get the AdditionApplication instance
>>> value = addition_app.addition(number1, number2) # call the addition method
>>> print(value)
9
```